# Displaying first n paragraphs of string using preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The code below shows the first paragraph of a string, but I'd like it to show the first three paragraphs:

```
preg_match("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/",$paragraphs,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

I'm new to regular expressions, so I've been struggling to figure this out.  Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/", $paragraphs, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];
echo $matches[0][1];
echo $matches[0][2];
```

When you use `preg_match_all`, each subarray in $matches gains a new entry for each  match.

See php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php for more info.

Comment: Also `(.*?)` preferrably, and the `/s` flag.

Comment: Right. Forgot to ungreedy the search. Good catch.

Comment: Also `/i` modifier too #JustInCase

Comment: Remove parentheses to get the p tags as well

/<p>.*<\/p>/